# I am receiving an IllegalAccessError when trying to run the class with the main() method in it

Tags: java

I am currently learning java and ran into this error while trying to run one of the examples in the book. The compilation of the Movie class proceeds without error, but when trying to run or compile the MovieTestDrive class, this happens:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class MovieTestDrive tried to access field Movie.title (MovieTestDrive is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader @1e4a7dd4; Movie is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at MovieTestDrive.main(MovieTestDrive.java:5)**

*This is the source code of both files:*

```
public class Movie {

    String title;
    String genre;
    int rating; 

    void playIt() {
        System.out.println("Playing the Movie");
    }
}




public class MovieTestDrive extends Movie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Movie one = new Movie();
            one.title = "Gone with the Stock";
            one.genre = "Drama";
            one.rating = -2;
        Movie two = new Movie();
            two.title = "Avengers";
            two.genre = "Action";
            two.rating = 8;
            two.playIt();
    }
}
```

If anyone knows why this is happening I would really appreciate the help in fixing, and more importantly understanding as to why this problem occurred in the first place.

Comment: How do you compile those two files?

Comment: Also, what is the error you get when you compile? Compiling and running are two different things, are you trying to compile or are you trying to run?

Comment: ive tried both and ive got it to compile and run which is great thanks to @Rob Evans help. now im having an issue while running the class ` Error: Could not find or load main class .\MovieTestDrive.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /\MovieTestDrive/class `

Comment: When you run a java class just type `java MovieTestDrive` don't put path information, and don't put file extentions.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `playIt()` Method public and the field variables `public` so they're accessible:

```java
class Movie {

    public String title;
    public String genre;
    public int rating;

    public void playIt() {
        System.out.println("Playing the Movie");
    }
}

class MovieTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Movie one = new Movie();
        one.title = "Gone with the Stock";
        one.genre = "Drama";
        one.rating = -2;
        Movie two = new Movie();
        two.title = "Avengers";
        two.genre = "Action";
        two.rating = 8;
        two.playIt();
    }
}
```

public methods/fields will be visible to classes making use of the `Movie` class everywhere. Without specifying the access-modifier of the method, it gets package-private access by default - i.e. only classes in the same package can access the methods/fields.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

As a principal, grant the least amount of privilege necessary for the field/method to work. So we want to keep access as restricted as possible, as a principal... `private` being the typical value for class fields, and `private`/`public`/`protected` for class methods.

Comment: thank you i changed them to public and it compiled but now it is not running and returning < Error: Could not find or load main class .\MovieTestDrive.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /\MovieTestDrive/class >. Ive always assumed that making the class public would make all its contents public too.

Comment: I've amended the above response to reflect the changes if you put them both in the same file (no public on the class names since they won't match the filename)

Comment: yes both the classes are in one folder and MovieTestDrive should be public why wouldnt it be?

Comment: it just depends what files you have them in - if they're separate then the public access modifier can be present. If not, then its not required as the classes will be able to "see" one another (i.e. they're both in-scope of one another)

Comment: That isn't true necessarily. If you leave off a modifier then it is package private. So any class in the same package can access them. Being in the same file will mean the classes are also in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `extends Movie` from the MovieTestDrive class

Comment: yeah ive already tried doing that it didnt work before which is why i implemented it in the first place hoping it would.

Comment: It still shouldn't extend Movie. MovieTestDrive seems to be a limited database of Movie objects rather than a Movie itself.